# Webpack using Typescript: Common settings in both configs, so which take precedence?

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, tsconfig

I am in the initial stages of converting a javascript (with webpack) project into a typescript project and one of the many confusions I have is that their appears to be some configuration settings that can appear in webpack and typescript, so which takes precedence?

(I'm currently working on a node cli application).

Eg, the primary example is which files are included in compilation.

In webpack config, you can specify which input files are selected with rules:

```
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /index.ts/,
        use: 'shebang-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.ts(x?)$/,
        use: 'ts-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.json$/,
        use: 'json-loader'
      }
    ]
  },
```

As you can see from above, I'm using various loaders for different file types.

Then my initial tsconfig.json is as follows:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "lib": [
      "es5", "es2015", "es6", "dom"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "lib/**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

So what is the true nature of the interaction between webpack and typescript? I have not been able to discern this from typescript or webpack documentation. Both appear to be able to specify the input files that are included in compilation.

Another (probably better example) is the output file. In webpack config I have the following:

```
  output: {
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs',
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'application-bundle.js'
  }
```

which defines 'application-bundle.js' is the output file inside the 'dist' folder.

In the tsconfig, you can have something like the following:

```
"outFile": "./dist/application-bundle.js",
```

(I currently do not define an outFile property, but I know you can do so, but in being able to do so, brings up ambiguities and hence confusion). So in this scenario, does webpack override typescript or vice-versa? What is the recommended strategy?

There are probably more typescript/webpack crossovers that are going to cause confusion, but the 2 that I have described so far are the most upfront and pressing issues I need to understand, thanks.

EDIT: Having thought about it, I also need another clarification. I am guessing when you build a TS/WP project, the TS compiler runs first creates all the .js files (let's say in the .dist folder). Then webpack bundles all the generated .js files. So assuming this is correct, do I then need to configure webpack to use as its input the .js files in the dist folder instead of the .js files inside the project source (ie everything under ./lib which is where my source js files are)?

I was hoping to convert my project in an incremental manner so what I have just said does not really fit my needs. Webpack would need to pick up some .js files from ./dist and some files from ./lib which have not yet been converted to typescript. I don't know how to modify the project for incremental upgrade.

Comment: no problem! (I'm just currently reviewing your answer)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> [...] there appears to be some configuration settings that can appear in webpack and typescript, so which takes precedence?

You are right on the point that there is some natural redundancy in the configuration when Webpack is combined with TypeScript. Lets pick up your first question:

> which files are included in compilation? [...] Another example is the output file. [...] So in this scenario, does webpack override typescript or vice-versa? What is the recommended strategy?

Simply spoken, both TypeScript and Webpack process/transform input files and emit the output in a target directory structure or file bundle(s) - both need some input/output configuration info. TypeScript compiler can run on its own, and also be integrated as file processor as part of a bigger Webpack build. With `outFile` option TypeScript can even be seen as a mini-bundler on its own, as it *bundles* all `.ts`-files to a single target file.

To answer the question, if TypeScript or Webpack configuration takes precedence, it is important to understand, how Webpack works. I'll quote one of your  assumptions here:

> I am guessing when you build a TS/WP project, the TS compiler runs first creates all the .js files (let's say in the .dist folder). Then webpack bundles all the generated .js files.

That is not quite correct. But good you said that, as it sheds more light on your core understanding problem. Everything in Webpack starts with the [entry point](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/entry-points/) you specify in the config - if you will, that's the input. From this entry module, webpack considers all other transitively imported modules (e.g. via `import` or `require`) and creates a dependency tree.

Every file in the dependency tree can optionally be transformed by [Loaders](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/loaders/), which can also be chained like a file processing pipeline. So `ts-loader` and the underlying TypeScript compiler apply transformations for .ts/.tsx files with `test: /\.ts(x?)$/` predicate.

All in all you see, that Webpack considers your entry file, which leads to a bunch of further imported .ts/.tsx files (amongst your other file types, we neglect them here). And for each single file, the TypeScript loader will be invoked in the course of the loader processing pipeline. Therefore, it is inherent that TypeScript I/O config will be ignored and Webpack's `entry`/`output` configuration takes precedence in the build. All other TypeScript related settings are taken from `tsconfig.json`, as described in the [ts-loader docs](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader#configuration): `"The tsconfig.json file controls TypeScript-related options so that your IDE, the tsc command, and this loader all share the same options."`

> I was hoping to convert my project in an incremental manner

It is perfectly fine to migrate from [JavaScript to TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/migrating-from-javascript.html) in a stepwise manner!

Hope, that helps.

Comment: Hi ford04, thanks for your answer, it  really helps a lot. I have taken the view that instead of conbverting an existing project. I am going to start a new typescript project and incrementally transfer over the functionality. Its the only way to manage the tsumani of confusing typescript errors (particluarly with modules/namespace/imports/exports) I'm seeing currently. Cheers

Comment: If it's a small project and affordable for you, go for it! If you want to give it a try in one project, I think it's worth to look at the last link for js migration, especially set 
` "allowJs": true` in tsconfig.json. You could also take a look at all the `--strict` settings in [compiler options](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) or set `"strict: false"` to be able to compile the project and enforce stricter settings gradually.

Comment: Great thanks. It still makes sense for me to start a new project because I'm new to typescript (and knowing C# and OO doesnt give any advantages in trying to solve typescript/javascript issues as I thought it would). If I start a new project then I can handle 1 error at a time instead of trying to solve a multitude of issues all at once.